# Why is the chandrayaan 3 mission taking 40 days to land? A

Tags: trajectory

The Apollo missions took only 3 days. And I think Artemis too took some 26 days.

Also, what do you guys think about the 53 million dollar budget?

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: Welcome to space! In future, best to avoid multiple questions in one post, and opinion-based questions.